# Compiling tutorial programs on FFMPEG

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

How do i compile the sample programs given in FFMPEG. i am not able to compile as i get 
error as CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO undeclared. Can any one please suggest me how to compile the programs. I am using ubuntu 11.

This is the first example:

```
$ gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz
```

This is the output I got:

```
tutorial01.c: In function ‘main’: tutorial01.c:77:3: warning: ‘dump_format’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1462)
tutorial01.c:82:51: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tutorial01.c:82:51: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Version info:

```
ffmpeg version git-N-30430-ga52f598, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 31 2011 14:21:08 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
  libavutil    51.  3. 0 / 51.  3. 0
  libavcodec   53.  6. 1 / 53.  6. 1
  libavformat  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 0 / 53.  1. 0
  libavfilter   2. 11. 0 /  2. 11. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 0 /  0. 14. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
```

Comment: Post the actual build command(s) and error message(s)

Comment: This is the first example                                         ffmpegexam$ gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz                                                                      
This is the output i got.                  tutorial01.c: In function ‘main’:
tutorial01.c:77:3: warning: ‘dump_format’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:1462)
tutorial01.c:82:51: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tutorial01.c:82:51: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: for future reference you should edit your question to add additional information such as this - I've done this for you on this occasion. From the limited information available it looks like you're trying to build tutorial examples that relate to a much older version of ffmpeg ?

Comment: @PaulR: thanks a lot for the information. Please let me know whether the version i am using is correct or not..

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing `CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO` with `AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO`. You may run into other differences. Consider finding newer tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. will check and post the result. Can u suggest me finding a new tutorial. Please